# Do I have to prime if I'm force carbonating?

Tags: kegging, priming

Time has slipped and I have a brew that needs to be tapped on Saturday. It was in primary for 10 days, and has been in secondary for about 3 weeks now. This will be my first time kegging. If I am going to force carbonate, do I still need to prime when I put it in the keg?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if your beer is ready to drink, you can go ahead and hook up your gas and then start force-carbing. You can let it sit for a few days at carbing pressure or you can give it a kick start by hooking your gas line up to your OUT port on your keg and gently rolling it back and forth on your lap. I prefer to give it time in the keg as it helps you have nice clear beer.

Comment: I roll the keg on the floor under my foot, seems easier than on the lap. You can hear the co2 entering solution with each shake. If you do the shake method to quickly carb, it's then even more important to purge the keg free of oxygen to avoid staling the beer prematurely.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I'm not too concerned about it staling quickly as I assume it will be gone on the day of tapping.